# Keep track of which user fully downloaded a file

Tags: 7

I'm looking for a solution to check which users fully downloaded a specific download/file.
I found several solutions to detect whether a download/file is completed.
F.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download
But this use case is quiet different. I need to retrieve a list of people who downloaded the file afterwards.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have file_entity installed, you can use hook_file_transfer() with a custom function my_custom_registration($file, $user) that registers which user downloaded which file
The starting code for that is :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_file_transfer().
 *
 * @param type $uri
 */
function my_module_file_transfer($uri) {
  global $user;
  $files = file_load_multiple(array(), $conditions = array('uri' => $uri));
  if (!empty($files)) {
    $file = reset($files);
    my_custom_registration($file, $user);
  }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: That won't help to confirm that the file has been downloaded, just that the download was requested/started at some point

Comment: @izus, thanks for you answer but as Clive mentioned this only keeps track of the requested/started downloads not if the file was 100% completely downloaded.